# Icon size for retina displays?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

My Chrome Packaged App has 3 icon sizes for the moment: 16x16, 48x48 and 128x128. But I haven't find any information about a 256x256 icon for retina displays like Chromebook Pixel or rMBP.

I haven't these computers so I cannot test, did someone know if Chrome use a big icon format when you launch a Chrome Packaged App on a high-resolution display?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put a 256x256 icon in your manifest, Chrome will make use of it wherever necessary. When Chrome creates icons for the app in the operating system's menu, it will store the full resolution icon, so it will be up to the operating system to decide when to use them.

To the best of my knowledge:

- On Windows, you will hardly ever see it, but if you create a Desktop icon, then set the Desktop to show "Extra Large" icons, you will see it. (I don't know why anyone would ever do that.)
- On Mac, the dock can be set to show a large icon when the user mouses over, and on a retina display it probably uses the 256x256 icon (but I haven't tested this).

On a Chromebook, I don't think the icons are ever shown big enough that the 256x256 icon would be useful, even on a high-res display. However, this may change in the future, so it is always good to supply an icon in as high resolution as possible.

So in summary, it is worthwhile making a 256x256 icon if it's not too much trouble, because it will be used in some situations. But an ordinary user will probably not see it very often.